# Integrating Facebook and Twitter Profile Image in my apps

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

How to add my Facebook and Twitter Profile Image in to my apps? How to crop that profile image to a particular size?

I am trying this facebook profile image from other problem

```
 ImageView user_picture;
 userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
 userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

from:- [Get user image from Facebook Graph-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841710/get-user-image-from-facebook-graph-api)

But How to find id of facebook profile user id of particular persons.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you need to use Facebook and Twitter API to achieve what you want in a dynamic and proper way.

Instead of getting the image and other stuff with URL and hardcoded way just use the APIS.

The simplest way would be.

- Implement the APIS to your application.
- Let the user login with either of these.
- And then get the information that you need by using the API methods.

Check these for more info to use the APIs.

Facebook Java API - http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

Twitter4j - http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html