# Using Facebook SDK to download and show image

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to download a profile picture (https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/picture) from Facebook using the Android Facebook SDK:

```
asyncFacebookRunner.request("19292868552" + "/picture", new BaseRequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        System.out.println(response);
        byte[] imageBytes = response.getBytes();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        System.out.println(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Exception ex) {

    }
});
```

The problem is, that the `bitmap` is null. This is the logcat:

```
11-10 20:15:56.540: I/System.out(20930): ������JFIF����������������;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 95����C��             ����C������2��2"��������������������������  �����������}��!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������    ���������w��!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������������?������{���(�B�K#UQ�$��޾l�?�^�/��τV�x�TL�j�X�}A����!��_�u�����f���ɨxW����A9�O����&`É�c��$���G��O���G����=�7;b'���8�F�OZ��xS�������Q�u����Yy�3�f�=GF���_�c뿊�V�3�~�{��7>6���H-"�%�������7�#��1S�e���kS���ߦ]���m�J�O�۴� T0�rJ�V��MX�?g���I�_c��λg����jJ$Dtr�mmFK����`�N�+̾.��_���ioK�/�����e�����y$y��|���9���?P�V�<=v��[z+uQ�C��zШ��{�^���/�*���H��woc>��[׋LM��F�bu$��P����Gב][M#���Ċ� S�p}8#�������.?fOY�y��_��Ki&����,v�:23q��`1�O85�����������NxSO�_�]F8����z�w31��[��Edl�ʱ�|�k��NUprQ�cv��ڻ~���S��g��ɷ��'o�W���=��QFW��������~���}������,��Uԫ���$�'�5�ľ�.���S3Aye;G$g)є��k��s�w���v�O��?�tԫ���t^c��_��oG�1�?�_����Z��~��G����]G��V��Wx��/�_0��P��O"67���$�_{>Z��^r>���i�>�"�>�t+I%�d���J��˕y$?<�;�B�W���$��=4��?�Y�������4߉��x[�M݆��M�Q��[<�   A�7d��^�,e9�o���h��)RN�yw������������+�;"����h�'�4M7���^��� ��1�!`��P�G���ƖD�о��v��K?��5�I���������_��.�.����fQ��R���$�bc���v.���$�{~Ǻq�㧁�+�|g�����yeW6�q�$��$���վ���,e:Q]V��^���D�ޯ�ڊ8��h�ď�������.G�����7A�~j�چ��t���0��;��đN�f��F��0�ߞ+��9����9�<���9�[��qab����p�8��8����_�,���)YP�+¿m��y�����Ho��Y��۷�y������r�ڤ��6�ܭ�_a��^#N�����+�[}�߿K�>3*�^n�>7��Ƙ��_O�i���_u����h���㧅,��1j�^9�H�յĳ�ƞ�7v�$��%�@@Q��2p0{?�+G��?���&��~��-j][7"ԣO��3[�w_1�2�#)�{h��!�����>1|E����o��rt_kZN��j�jb�%��H���$��s�Fp9�����s\��I4��֭'�v�եe��>s��zPK�R����+�U�wt�OW���+1s!���8��ز��������������<[�O�I���4M7V��Y�(H��G*Ɉ��v������_�~)����Gč3⿍�%g{�i_f��O0[)r䪟�>O��Gb+����,b�ª����+��u\GO����Ԥ����
11-10 20:15:56.540: D/skia(20930): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
11-10 20:15:56.540: I/System.out(20930): null
```

How can I get a bitmap to show in an `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the new Facebook SDK this problem doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct to me, you also get input as the print shows. I found an another example[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841825/969325) for user picture. The example uses Url and inputstream indstead of byte array, maybe that would work for you.